# How to customize enhanced link attribution for Google Analytics in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm installing Google Analytics on a website using Google Tag Manager and I want to enable Enhanced Link Attribution.

I've enabled Enhanced Link Attribution in my Google Analytics Property settings and I enabled link tracking on my Google Analytics Settings Variable in Tag Manager. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution) states, you can customize the maximum number of levels in the DOM to look for existing IDs, but I can't find an option to change this anywhere in Google Tag Manager.

This is the sample code provided in the documentation link above. The only way I've found to get this working is by uninstalling Google Analytics from Tag Manager and manually installing the tracking code with the modifications to every page of my website.

```js
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'linkid', {
  'cookieName': '_ela',
  'duration': 45,
  'levels': 5
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Google Analytics tag tick "Enable overriding settings in this tag", then click on "More Settings" -> "Fields To Set" and finally "Add Field"

When you click on field name "linkid" should be in the drop-down already, select it and set the value to the object you have in your example. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Do you know the format for these settings?

Comment: My reference is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution 

It looks like 'linkid' expects a key-value array, one of whose elements has the key 'levels' and an integer value of 'the number of levels in the DOM to look to find an existing ID'.

I'm going to try setting the 'linkid' field to the value of {'levels':6}